# Is there a better way to compose a message based on conditions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string, ecmascript-6

I am trying to display a message based on user activity, the message changes based on how many users came back in the payload `others`. The following code works but it is bulky and feels off somehow.

What I'm doing:

- Less than 3: “Along with Billy Bob and Tom Thomason.”
- Exactly 3: “Along with Billy Bob, Tom Thomason, and Mary Maryland.”
- Greater than 3: “Along with Billy Bob, Tom Thomason, and 3 others.”

```
const handleActivitySummary = useCallback(
  (verb, others) => {
    if (verb === "SHARED_POST") {
      return "shared a post";
    } else {
      const userJoined = verb === "MEMBER_ADDED";
      let summary;

      userJoined
        ? (summary = `has joined ${post.slug}`)
        : (summary = `has left ${post.slug}`);

      if (others && others.length < 3) {
        summary += ` along with ${others
          .map((user) => user.full_name)
          .join(", ")
          .replace(/, ([^,]*)$/, " and $1")}`;
      }
      if (others && others.length === 3) {
        summary += ` along with ${others
          .map((user) => user.full_name)
          .join(", ")
          .replace(/, ([^,]*)$/, ", and $1")}`;
      }
      if (others && others.length > 3) {
        const newArray = others.slice(0, 3);
        const usersLeft = others.length - newArray.length;
        summary += ` along with ${newArray
          .map((user) => user.full_name)
          .join(", ")} and ${usersLeft} ${pluralize(usersLeft, "other")}`;
      }

      return summary;
    }
  },
  [post]
);
```

Comment: Since your code is working and you are looking for improvements/enhancements, you should post it on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Start by looking for duplicate code (there's quite a bit) and handle of that in a single place, then handle the differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can try solving this by writing a custom Javascript helper method like below**

```js
"use strict";
const getSummary = (memberNames) => {
    const memberCount = memberNames.length;
    const statement = `along with `.concat(memberNames.slice(0, 3).join(", "));
    if (memberCount > 0 && memberCount <= 3) {
        return statement.replace(/, ([^,]*)$/, " and $1");
    }
    if (memberCount > 3) {
        return statement.replace(/, ([^,]*)$/, "").concat(` and ${memberCount - 2} others`);
    }
    return "";
};
console.log(getSummary([]));
console.log(getSummary(["Alice"]));
console.log(getSummary(["Alice", "Bob"]));
console.log(getSummary(["Alice", "Bob", "Cameron"]));
console.log(getSummary(["Alice", "Bob", "Cameron", "Dion"]));
```